# Apache wicket uses any java frameworks internally

Tags: java, apache, frameworks, wicket

Does Apache wicket use any JAVA EE frameworks internally for mapping the form data to the underlying models and for form submission and page redirection?

Answer (score 3):

No, the only JEE technology it depends on is the Servlet standard. Wicket supports integration with other JEE modules like CDI or Bean Validation, but they are optional.